# Allow specific domain OU to access to the asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, web-config, authorization

I have an Asp.net application that works on domain with AD authentication. All AD users are members of Domain/Users, but they are in different Organization Unit folder OU, as following:
dmain/Dept/sales
dmain/Dept/marketing
dmain/Dept/IT
dmain/Dept/HQ
so what I want is to allow only the users under the HQ to have access to the application, I have tried:

```
<allow users="domain/Dept/HQ" />
```

but didn't work.
Is it possible to do this?
Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to filter access by OU, no. But if you can maintain a group with all those users, then you can use the "roles" feature:

```
<allow roles="DOMAIN\HQGroup" />
```